# Filling ranges based on some specified strings

Tags: java, parsing

The method takes two parameters.  If I call it with two parameters

first : `["0-1000:2","1000-2000:3"]`

second:  `initial`

then these are the expected outputs:

1. First range:

   ```
   rangeId: 0-1000,
   from: 0,
   to: 1000,
   issuingRange: initial,
   minUsers: 2
   ```
2. Second range:

   ```
   rangeId: 1000-2000
   from: 1000
   to: 2000
   issuingRange: initial
   minUsers: 3
   ```

This code is working but I would like to improve it. Can I use streams in Java 8? Any other change or suggestion can make the code better?

---

```
private  List<Range> fillRanges(Object roleList, String issuingRange) {

if (roleList != null) {
    List<String> rangeList2 = null;
    if (roleList instanceof ArrayList<?>) {

        rangeList2 = (ArrayList<String>) roleList;
    } else if (roleList instanceof String) {
        rangeList2 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(roleList));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ((ArrayList) rangeList2).size(); i++) {
        String rangeId = "";
        String from = "";
        String to = "";
        String minUsers = "";
        String info = ((ArrayList) rangeList2).get(i).toString();

        logger.debug("info: " + info);

        if (info.indexOf(":") > -1) {
            rangeId = info.substring(0, info.indexOf(":"));
            minUsers = info.substring(info.indexOf(":") + 1);
            if (info.indexOf("-") > -1) {
                from = info.substring(0, info.indexOf("-"));
                to = info.substring(info.indexOf("-")+1, info.indexOf(":"));
            }
        } else {
            rangeId = info;
            if (info.indexOf("-") > -1) {
                from = info.substring(0, info.indexOf("-"));
                to = info.substring(info.indexOf("-")+1);
            }
            minUsers = "0";
        }

        ranges.add(new Range(rangeId, from, to, issuingRange, minUsers));
    }
}
return ranges;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1231/42632).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function seems to be abusing the `roleList` parameter.  There are two modes in which this function can be called: with a single `String` (in which case one `Range` is added), or with an `ArrayList<String>` (in which case one `Range` is added for each element of the list).  If you call it with any other kind of `Object`, then the code crashes with a `NullPointerException`.  That's not good design.

Rather, you should define two separate functions to handle those two modes of operation.  The list-handling version simply chains to the string-handling version of the function.

```
private void fillRanges(List<String> roleSpecs, String issuingRange) {
    for (String roleSpec : roleSpecs) {
        this.fillRanges(roleSpec, issuingRange);
    }
}

private void fillRanges(String roleSpec, String issuingRange) {
    …
}
```

To implement the latter function, I would avoid slicing and dicing using substrings.  Since this is a parsing problem that involves pattern recognition, I would use a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) instead to capture the substrings of interest.

```
private static final Pattern RANGE_REGEX = Pattern.compile(
    "^(?<rangeId>(?<from>\\d*)-?(?<to>\\d*))(?::(?<minUsers>\\d+))?$"
);

private void fillRanges(String roleSpec, String issuingRange) {
    logger.debug("Role: " + roleSpec);
    Matcher m = RANGE_REGEX.matcher(roleSpec);
    if (!m.matches()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(roleSpec);
    }
    ranges.add(new Range(
        m.group("rangeId"),
        m.group("from"),
        m.group("to"),
        issuingRange,
        m.group("minUsers") == null ? "0" : m.group("minUsers")
    ));
}
```